# Yii2 RESTful API doesn't accept request in header "Accept: text/plain"

Tags: rest, yii2

My RESTful API doesn't work If I set "Accept: text/plain" in request header and It returns an Error page with title "unsupported media type".
But It works nice If "Accept: application/json" or "Accept: application/xml" is set in request header.

Somebody knows what changes I must do so My API works on accepting request with "Accept: text/plain" in header ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Content negotiation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html#content-negotiation) in the guide.

Essentially, you configure your application's [content negotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html#$formats-detail) to accept `text/plain`, and then [add a formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$formatters-detail) for this media type.

Of course, you'll need to implement the formatter class yourself using the [ResponseFormatterInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-responseformatterinterface.html).